# Very basic python checl

Tags: python

all fairly new to python and was introduced to it at school and was just having a bit of fun creating a black-jack game. My problem is that I have a a function that selects a random number/value from a list and adds a random house (diamonds,clubs,spades and hearts). I use two of those function to give your cards. But for the game to work, I need a variable which would be a sum of the random numbers (used to make the card). It allows the player to select whether they want 1 or 11 when the get an ace

my defienition is as follows:
(CARDS AND HOUSES ARE BOTH LISTS)

```
def random_card_pick():
  card = (random.choice(Cards))
  if card == 'ace':
    card = (random.choice(Cards))
    ace = int(input('you have an ace. 1 or 11 ?'))
    if ace == 1 :
      card = 1 
    else :
      card = 11
  house = (random.choice(houses))
  print(card,'of',house)
```

THIS IS REPEATED TWO TO GET TWO CARDS

How would i call the definition and then separate the number from it?
or somehow add the two cards together to get a total?
any solutions to this problem would be helpful thank you.
And also please say if this makes no sence

this is what i tried

```
def random_card_pick():
  card = (random.choice(Cards))
  if card == 'ace':
    card = (random.choice(Cards))
    ace = int(input('you have an ace. 1 or 11 ?'))
    if ace == 1 :
      card = 1 
    else :
      card = 11
  house = (random.choice(houses))
  card1 = print(card,'of',house)
```

Comment: Your function should return a tuple: `return card, house`. The caller can then assign two variables: `card, house = random_card_pick()`

Comment: thank you. And so this should allow me to add the two together ?

Comment: If you call it twice and set two variables, like `card1` and `card2`, you can add them together with `card1 + card2`

Comment: I know you're just getting started, but you shouldn't ask the player whether they want the ace to be 1 or 11.  The principle is that the ace is always 11 unless the total is more than 21, in which case it is 1.  The danger of asking is that if they get dealt A and 5 and choose the A to be 11, and then ask for a hit and get a face card, you would show them as a bust, when in fact they have not.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return your card, then you can call your function as much as you like:

```
def random_card_pick():
  card = (random.choice(Cards))
  if card == 'ace':
    # card = (random.choice(Cards)) <--commented out, this is superfluous
    ace = int(input('you have an ace. 1 or 11 ?'))
    if ace == 1 :
      card = 1 
    else :
      card = 11
  house = (random.choice(houses))
  return card, house

card1, house1 = random_card_pick()
card2, house2 = random_card_pick()
cardtotal = card1 + card2

print(f'Your two cards are the {card1} of {house1} and the {card2} of {house2}. Your total is {cardtotal}')
```

Comment: The only problem here is the possibility of drawing the same card twice.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but you will want to do something like

```
card1 = random_card_pick()
card2 = random_card_pick()
print('total: ', card1+card2)
```

It would also be a good idea to return and store the house's cards by returning a tuple

```
def random_card_pick():
  card = (random.choice(Cards))
  if card == 'ace':
    card = (random.choice(Cards))
    ace = int(input('you have an ace. 1 or 11 ?'))
    if ace == 1 :
      card = 1 
    else :
      card = 11
  house = (random.choice(houses))
  return card, house

card1, housecard1 = random_card_pick()
card2, housecard2 = random_card_pick()
```